# Converting SQL Query to Mongo Aggregation

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I am very new to mongodb and hence having extensively worked with SQL, I want to try to do the same with mongo as I did with SQL query.

I have 2 collections:

**Flights**
Attributes: 
ID(STRING)
VERIFIED(STRING)
VALID(STRING)

**Mission**
Attributes:
ID(STRING)
FLIGHTS(ARRAY OF FLIGHTS)

I need to retrieve the data according to a SQL query which looks like (theoretically):

```
SELECT VERIFIED, VALID 
FROM FLIGHT
WHERE FLIGHT.ID IN
 ( SELECT FLIGHTS
FROM MISSION
WHERE MISSION.ID = "somestring"
AND
FLIGHT.ID = MISSION.FLIGHTS)
```

Example of documents in the collections:

**Flight**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c4ae5b6a2ac3bc9f2e1b943"),
  "verified": "true",
  "valid": "true"
}
```

**Mission**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c5acdd8bbf999dc34d96de7"),
  "flights":[
      ObjectId("5c4ae5b6a2ac3bc9f2e1b943"),
      ObjectId("5c4ae5eea2ac3bc9f2e1b961")
      ]
 }
```

I'm very confused as how I should use "$lookup" and "$unwind".

In simpler terms the aim of my aggregation is:

**I need to retrieve VALID and VERIFIED of all FLIGHTS that is present in a MISSION whose ID is "somestring"**

Comment: Could you show sample data of both the collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.mission.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { "_id": "Here is mission Object Id" }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "flight",
          let: { flightIds: "$flights" },
          pipeline: [
           {
              $match: {
                $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$flightIds" ]}
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "result"
        }
      }
    ])
```

You can try It on [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jub5aZOwx2g)

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your answer. But I seem to be getting this error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { flightIds: "$flights" } is type object`. Any reason why this would occur?

Comment: Please update your mongoDB version 3.4 to version 3.6 or above. Thanks.